# What is the bandwidth through an uplink port when using link aggregation on a switch?

Tags: networking, switch, gigabit-ethernet

To use link aggregation you need a smart managed or managed switch. I'm wondering if you really could get 2 Gbps if you aggregate two 1 Gbps port. Full duplex is on each port but the upstream port would be only a normal port (not a dedicated uplink for this).

How much speed can this port carry? Is it still 1 Gbps or does link aggregation indeed delivers 2 Gbps (spread around all clients)? I know if you take full duplex into account you have to duble the speeds. But I don't think that you then could carry 4 Gbps through the uplink port. You also have to be aware of the used cable (how much speed can a Cat 6 cable have for example). If the uplink port goes to another switch do you would also get 4 Gbps on the port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a port-bundling / link-aggregation then  you should configure PAGP / LACP on both the links, hence two 1 GBps links can deliver 2 GBps. If you are using two 1 GBps links then there is no question of 4 GBps throughput.

You cannot configure link-aggregation on a shared upstream link, its of no use if configured. Many vendor devices will not allow shared with link-aggregation.

Comment: So bundling two 1 GBps port gives you 2 GBps at maximum. I haven't fully understood your last point. The goal is to use link-aggregation for a server so that he has two connections to the same switch. Of course the upstream link is shared between the two bundled ports and the remaining ports of the switch (but currently there are no other devices on the switch). The question for me is does it help to have link-aggregation in this case? Because the upstream link goes to another switch which multiple other devices connecting to the server.

Comment: If you need 2 GBps throughput from Server to Switch, then you can configure link-aggregation. So that all the users who are connected to that Switch should able to access the Server without any latency. (But in your case this upstream Switch is connected to another upstream Switch --> If this Switch supports 2 GBps then its work configuring link-aggregation). Else you can use two 1 GBps links on the Server to Switch as failover links (Redundancy)

Comment: Are there any 2 GBps switches out there? Haven't seen anyone. Or do you mean creating another link aggregation between the two switches?  The failower would only help a little, because if the whole switch would fail, it wouldn't help either.

Comment: After 1 GBps like we only have 10 Gig fiber, you will again have to do link-aggregation between two 1 Gig links to get 2 Gigs.

Comment: Ok, you would also need link aggregation between the two switches (and one switch which can aggregate 2x2 links). Thanks for clarification.